# Brans-Dicke vacuum cosmology?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

Has anyone heard of papers describing Brans-Dicke vacuum cosmology solutions?

I'd be interested to know if the following calculations make sense.

The Brans-Dicke action for a Universe dominated by the cosmological constant $\Lambda$ can be written as:
$$S=\int d^4x \sqrt{g}\Big[-\frac{1}{8w}\phi^2R+\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi+\Lambda\Big]$$
where $\phi$ is the scalar field, $R$ is the Ricci scalar and $w$ is a dimensionless parameter.

I assume that the cosmological constant $\Lambda$ implies a vacuum energy density with equation of state $p=-\rho$.

I then plug this equation of state into the Brans-Dicke equations of motion for FRW cosmology to obtain a static solution with mass scale $\phi \sim t$.

Crucially I assume that $\phi \sim a$. I assume that the change of scale $a(t)$ of the universe is entirely due to the change of the mass scale due to $\phi$.

I used the following paper which helpfully gives the generalized Brans-Dicke equations of motion for FRW cosmology (Eqns 7,8,9 with equation of state $p=-\rho$ and scalar field mass $m=0$) :

https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0604082v4

Maybe, as Eddington speculated in "The Expanding Universe", the atoms are shrinking (as their energy increases with mass scale $\phi$) rather than space expanding?

I haven't seen any references to such a simple solution which seems surprising to me. Surely I can't be the first person to think of it?!

I think that the whole solar system, including its Schwartzschild metric, will simply shrink in a manner inversely proportional to the cosmic time $t$. But I presume that one could still use Einstein's theory locally, as the Planck length would also shrink at the same rate, provided that the time scale of the solar system dynamics is much smaller than the current age of the Universe.

Thus experiments on the solar system would not rule out Brans-Dicke theory for the Universe as a whole. The main experimental consequence would be an apparent cosmological redshift due to the difference in mass scale between absorbing and emitting atoms (the energy of the emitted photon itself does not change with mass scale).

Comment: You look at Valerio Faraoni's book: Cosmology in scalar tensor theories;  and Fujii&Maeda book: scalar tensor theories of gravitation.

Answer (score 0):

Googling quickly turned up this: Brans-Dicke gravity with a cosmological constant smoothes out ΛCDM tensions
Joan Sola, Adria Gomez-Valent, Javier de Cruz Perez, Cristian Moreno-Pulido, https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.02554

They claim to be able to resolve some of the current tension between ΛCDM and experiment by taking $\omega\approx -300$. (Note the negative sign.)

What they don't seem to address is that solar system tests from Cassini-Huygens require $\omega \gtrsim 40,000$.

> People claim that the Brans-Dicke theory has been ruled out by observation but maybe it hasn’t been ruled out if it applies to the whole universe dominated by vacuum energy?

The strongest evidence against BD (constraining $\omega$ to values much bigger than unity) is from solar system tests, so it's not dependent on cosmology or modeling of vacuum energy.

Comment: It is not clear from the post what the question is. Can you rephrase the question with a bit more elaboration?

Comment: I was thinking that Brans-Dicke theory maybe valid for the Universe as a whole if it is dominated by a large vacuum energy. This would imply a static Universe with a global linearly increasing energy scale $\phi$. One would then apply normal Einsteinian gravity to localized systems like the solar system.

Comment: I was just wondering if people have heard of a static vacuum solution to the Brans-Dicke theory incorporating a mass scale $\phi \sim t$.